# how to separates the display into 2 parts, transparent and solid.in xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view

i want to make a custom layouts like this picture :
[image: my custom layout]

at this layout, there is a circle button and separates by two color types in layout, first is transparent, and second is solid color. how to separate this button in two types of color?

and i am use library AndroidSlidingUpPanel from [umano](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) , how to disable sliding up if panel layout reach anchor point or stop slide in the middle of screen?

this is so my source code, and not working, still show white background.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/map_height" />

                <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space"
        android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_place"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Taman Krida Budaya"
            android:textColor="@color/action_bar"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_center"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:cb_color="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        app:cb_pressed_ring_width="8dip" />

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_center"
        app:cb_color="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        app:cb_pressed_ring_width="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_nearby" />

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/space"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_center"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_rute"
        app:cb_color="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
        app:cb_pressed_ring_width="8dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us the code! :-)

Comment: Why don't you set the background color of the circle the same as the background?

Comment: @Darwind this is my update in source code, still show white background.